# How to limit size of uploaded image when using image component with xtype html5smartimage in cq5?

Tags: javascript, extjs, aem, xtype

For image component with xtype html5smartimage, 
I have tried the **sizeLimit** option of html5smartimage wih **string** value **1** assuming will not be able to upload image exceeding 1mb but was able to upload image of a greater size. 
I did not find any info on the value of sizeLimit except for the fact the default 0 means no limit to the image upload size. 
Please do share any info on sizeLimit option?

Alternatively, tried listener on image dialog on event **loadimage**. 
Is able to read image size using this.fileInfo.size
Next is to call the **clear** action of the dialog, when the size exceeds limit. I am yet to figure out where is the out of box clear action of dialog implemented any insight on this would be of great help. 
crop, rotate are other actions that are available along with the clear action in the image dialog of the component.

Also what would be the best way of doing it or if anyone has solution or suggestions pls do share your information.

Comment: @d33t do you have any sugestion on this

Comment: @rakhi4110 inviting your views on this

Comment: as mention by i.net there is a bug in extjs for this widget. And you can find the **sizeLimit** blocks behaviour just by **"clear"** the uploaded image and try again. It will block the image, and just by uploading a less size limit image again will upload later try uploading more size image will upload. its a uncertain behavior widget extjs bug.

Comment: @VAr Thanks got ur point that sizeLimit is a known cq bug. Another point is if I need to call clear from js how shall I do that,
 I tried looking its implementation but could not find. Any info on the "clear" action implementation or how can we call clear from a js.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug in extjs. A post exists to explain how to implement this limit for DAM asset UI at:

http://experience-aem.blogspot.co.uk/2014/12/aem-6-sp1-classic-ui-restrict-large-or-small-files-upload.html

You can probably leverage this to extend the smart image and extend the validation to check the file size.

HtH

PS: The logic is too long to fit in this answer box but the gist is around validation hooks. Try it from the article and see if it works for you.

Comment: ThankYou, I was able to find this. 
Need to restrict image upload from browse option upload from local. 
Any suggestion on the clear action of the dialog.